# Do I need in text citations for an article on a historical event if I have links?

Tags: publications, citations, writing

I am writing an article on a historical event chronicled by Plutarch and translated by the Harvard University Press and have used certain ideas and facts from his writings in my own article by summarizing some of his statements and combining it with my own ideas. I have a link to the writings that I have referred to at the end of the article, but I was wondering if I needed to add in any in text citations to give proper credit to him and translators of his work.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty clear-cut case where you need in-text citations, especially given the multiplicity of possible translations and editions available. Not doing so could definitely get you into trouble with plagiarism accusations if discovered after submission.